# How to get the email of the current userID in ASP.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, asp.net-membership, userid

I am using ASPMembership db in ASP.net (vb.net win form). How to get the email of the current userID in ASP.net vb.net. what the code looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function where sUt is a username

```
Public Shared Function userEmail(ByVal sUt As String) As String
    Dim u As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(sUt)
    Return u.Email.ToString
End Function
```